# Prevent Ctrl+C sent to child process being received by parent process too

Tags: python

Consider this very simple Python program:

```
import subprocess
import time
import signal
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = subprocess.Popen( ["timeout","5"] )
    time.sleep(1)
        
    print("PID is " + str(process.pid))
    process.send_signal( signal.CTRL_C_EVENT )
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print("Done")
    sys.exit(0)
```

When I run this (under Windows), console outputs:

```
  File "src\caid_utl\test\test_colcon_sigint.py", line 35, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
```

"Done" is not printed, parent process (this program) exited due to Ctrl+C being sent to child process.

How to get rid of that?

I see that catching `KeyboardInterrupt` fixes the issue:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = subprocess.Popen( ["timeout","5"] )
    time.sleep(1)
        
    try:
        print("PID is " + str(process.pid))
        process.send_signal( signal.CTRL_C_EVENT )
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ignored Ctrl+C from parent")
        pass
    
    print("Done")
    sys.exit(0)
```

But it makes no sense as the current program did not receive any keyboard interruption. Is there no alternative to this? A way to isolate parent and child processes for good?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: Excatly, thanks a lot!